# Why `padding:auto of parent div` does not same with `margin:auto of child div`?

Tags: html, css

To center the child div in the parent div, I often use `margin: auto` in css.

```css
.parent {
width:500px;
background: red;
}

.child {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background: blue;
margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

However, considering the box model, it is margin in the child position but padding in the parent position.

[image]

So, I try it.

```css
.parent {
width:500px;
background: red;
padding:auto;
}

.child {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

But this did not work like I thought. Do you know why?

Comment: `auto` is not a valid value for padding property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Inline to    `text-align: center;` to parent and  `display: inline-block;` to child

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't use the comment to thanks 
Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Anyways you're welcome.

Comment: In my experience this it the go-to method if you don't want to use flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer....this will solve your problem...
I've used the `padding` property

```css
.parent {
  
width:100px;
background: red;
padding-left:50%;
padding-right:50%;
}

.child {
  
width:100px;
height:100px;
background: blue;

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: width is increasing here